# Adobe CQ5 set default page properties

Tags: aem

Is it possible to set default page properties value in CQ5 when you created a page? Either by specifying it in templates, component, etc...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found it, just need to add the attributes directly under
templates//_jcr_content